# I can see her <run><running> slowly

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences

1. I can see her run slowly.
2. I can see her running slowly.

What is the meaningful difference between the two sentences above?

Comment: This has been discussed on this site before. Please see previous posts.

Comment: Can you give me the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is fine, however, "I can see her run", would better be used as describing something in the past, such a a dream:

"I still see her in my dreams. In them, I can see her run, fast, and away, into the dark".

Running would better be used for describing a real time event.